# Using a library written in C++ from a pure C project on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, shared-libraries

Found this statement [over at PSE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79258/c-programming-in-linux-in-2011/79273#79273): (quoting [Bob](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1696/bob-murphy))

> One of my favorite tricks on Windows and Mac OS doesn't work on Linux.
>   That trick is to write a DLL/dylib using C++ internals, export a C
>   API, and then be able to call into it from C programs. Linux shared
>   objects (the local equivalent of a DLL) can't really do that easily,
>   because the C++ standard library .so isn't in the default search path.
>   If you don't do a bunch of weird stuff to your C program, it will fail
>   as soon as it dynamically loads your .so at runtime: your .so will try
>   to dynamically load the standard library .so, it won't find it, and
>   then your program will exit.

I find that a bit odd. How accurate is this, factoring in possible differences between the major desktop/server distros of Linux?

<sub>This is purely out of curiosity, as I do Windows only (C++) programming at the moment.</sub>

---

As for Windows, I had to do a bit of lookup and I'll put it here for reference:
A C++ executable will normally link to [MSVCR*.DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for the C std library and [MSVCP*.DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for the stuff of the STL that resides in this DLL. Both of these either reside in the system32 directory, or, for the manifested stuff they'll reside in a subdir of Windows SideBySide cache (*winsxs folder*).

Comment: `I find that a bit odd. Is this accurate?` yes it is odd. No it isn't accurate. Also, there is no such thing as 'the linux' (distributions differ)

Comment: Note that (from memory:) VS2008+ MSVC runtime _must_ be loaded by manifest (or your program would complain at load time)

Comment: @sehe - Seems an odd point for major distributions to differ significantly.

Comment: @sehe - Yeah, but for 2010 it's back to the system32 folder IIRC.

Comment: I'm not saying there is a distribution that doesn't have the libstdc++ bits in the search path; I'm saying that the odd statement might be true for some foreign Linux distribution (Embedded Linux For Epson Chipsets Used In Refridgerators?)

Comment: I am doing this thing all the time, and it works fine. I am pretty sure that that guy had a totally unrelated problem and blamed the library search paths for it. I have never seen any linux where the libstdc++ is not in the /usr/lib[64]/ path

Comment: I don't think this is true at all - I mix C++ and `extern "C" {` to export a pure C interface all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing this thing all the time, and it works fine. I am pretty sure that that guy had a totally unrelated problem and blamed the library search paths for it.

I have never seen any linux distro where the `libstdc++.so` is not in the `/usr/lib[64]/` path.

Which also makes me wonder how C++ programs generally work for that guy, since to my knowledge the search path for `.so` files is language agnostic.

Maybe he always uses a special version and compiles all his programs with `-rpath` linker options? But even then, just adding that option to his C programs would work too.

> it will fail as soon as it dynamically loads your .so at runtime: your
>   .so will try to dynamically load the standard library .so, it won't
>   find it, and then your program will exit.

This makes me wonder if he solely refers to using `dlopen()` on your own `.so`. But also then it works just fine, unless you did not link the `.so` to your `libstdc++.so` (which would then be your own fault; it would be the same problem had you dependencies on any other library, regardless what language it was written in).